# Eclipse CDT: Imported Files are not included in build

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I imported files to the workspace and on using the imported classes it gives undefined function error. Looks like the files are not compiled. I am using Tizen IDE (built on Eclipse CDT). how to mark files to include in the build targets?

Comment: Kindly give more details,may be the makefile is not regenerated..

Answer (score 0):

We can add the newly added source folder under `Project Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Source Location tab`